# EF Code First, Where is the database specified?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have just created a test SQLServer Express DB when experimenting with EF Code First. The DB has been created correctly and all works. However I cannot see where the connectionstring is for this DB. I expected to find it in Web.config, but not so.

Thanks in advance,

Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF defaults to `./sqlexpress` for the server URI.  To change this, add a connectionstring with the name set to the same name as your DBContext class

For example, assuming your DbContext class is called "MyDbContext":

```
<add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="connectionStringHere" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```